# Schema validation in multi tenancy using hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, multi-tenant

How a multi tenancy application works based on

**Separate databases: Each tenant has its own database.**;

whether schema validation takes place or not?

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto validate is normally used ,

If a new tenant is dynamically added then is it possible to have a schema validation?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am facing the same problem. The schema-validation query doesnt probably know what is the data source.

Comment: I tried to override the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto validate method and passing all registered tenant database, before the start of the application

Comment: Hi @Cork Kochi, did you solve the problem?can you share the solution?

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${multitenancy.enabled:true} and '${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}'.equals('validate')")
@Component
public class DDLSchemaValidator implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private String[] tenants = {"tenant-1", "tenant-2", "tenant-3", "tenant-4"};

    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo = this.getPersistenceUnitInfo();

        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = this.emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getParentServiceRegistry();

        MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
        List<String> managedClassNames = persistenceUnitInfo.getManagedClassNames();
        for (String managedClassName : managedClassNames) {
            metadataSources.addAnnotatedClassName(managedClassName);
        }

        for (String tenantId: this.tenants) {
            MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder();
            metadataBuilder.applyImplicitSchemaName(tenantId);
            new SchemaValidator().validate(metadataBuilder.build());
        }
    }

    private PersistenceUnitInfo getPersistenceUnitInfo() {
        List<String> packagesToScan = EntityScanPackages.get(this.beanFactory).getPackageNames();
        if (packagesToScan.isEmpty() && AutoConfigurationPackages.has(this.beanFactory)) {
            packagesToScan = AutoConfigurationPackages.get(this.beanFactory);
        }

        DefaultPersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager = new DefaultPersistenceUnitManager();

        String[] packagesToScanArr = StringUtils.toStringArray(packagesToScan);
        persistenceUnitManager.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScanArr);
        persistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet();

        return persistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).